# Android webview with editable content loosing it's focus

Tags: android, webview, lost-focus

I've been trying to implement **RichTextEditor** using Webview. Webview is loaded with content editable html. To get focus on first time I need to click more than three times on webview. And It's also loosing it's focus when we click on end of entered text or end of the line again to get focus I need to click many times.

I have done following to make it focusable.

```
editorWebview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editorWebview.setFocusable(true);
editorWebview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

and request for focus in onTouch of ***Custom Webview***, when it lost it's focus.

```
switch (event.getAction())
{
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
            v.requestFocus();
        }
        break;
}
```

**NOTE:**
I'm running javascript to apply styles to text that entered in webview.

Please tell me what I am missing.

-Thanks

Comment: Did you create a custom WebView class and override the onTouch method or just implement an onTouchListener? The onTouchListener for WebView doesn't work on certain API versions.

Comment: I overrided onTouch method in my custom webview.

Comment: I want to use RichTextEditor in webview. Please, can you share your Custom Webview class! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed **eval command** that I used in script.Now I able to get rid of focus problem.